# Select multiple rows and one value from dual

Tags: sql, oracle

It's hard to explain but i would like to make query that display multiple rows in first column and one, same value in second column in Oracle
Something like this:

```
Select ('123', '456') First, 'abc' Second from dual;
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Hello! Please provide a table with the data that you actually want to query and the expected rows output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably shortest syntax is:

```
select column_value first, 'abc' second
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('123', '456', '789', 'A1', 'B70', 'C44'))
```

Result:

```
FIRST   SECOND
------  ------
123     abc
456     abc
789     abc
A1      abc
B70     abc
C44     abc
```

Answer (score 0):

use union all

```
Select '123' First, 'abc' Second from dual
union all
select '456','abc' from dual
```

Comment: I thought there would be some more simple solution, due to the fact I have 20 rows like that

Answer (score 0):

use union all

```
select '123', 'abc' from dual
 union all
select '456','abc' from dual
```

another similar way

```
 select * from (select '123' as col1 from dual
 union all
 select '456' from dual) a, (select 'abc' as col2 from dual) b

COL1    COL2
123     abc
456     abc
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ba7d163871363baa2c0dc0b320ee26ce)

Answer (score 0):

BAM! Change the `20` to however many rows you want.

```
select level as first, 'abc' as second
from dual
connect by level <= 20;
```

Comment: that's the best so far, thanks! but what if i want to use some specific characters, not just 1-20, but like more complex e.g. '95/665', '93/223' etc?

Comment: Well, I'd have to ask what's the purpose of this in the first place?  Please update your original post with the real reason you are asking this.  There is obviously more to the story and if you are looking for a way to generate a set of test data there are better ways depending on your needs.